# Changing behaviour of the 'tablenotes' environment

Tags: threeparttable

Is there a way to declare in the preamble so that the `tablenotes` environment has:

1. Single spacing between the item-lists.
2. The size is `\scriptsize`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{atkinson}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\begin{document}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Test table}
\begin{tabular}{c c c}
Test & Test & Test\tnote{a}\\
Test & Test & Test\tnote{b}\\
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item [a] Note 1.\\
\item [b] Note 2.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `\\`  after the first item is causing the excessive amount of vertical white space between the two items. Remove it to solve the first issue.

To change the font size of all `tablenotes` environments, you can use `\usepackage{etoolbox} \appto\TPTnoteSettings{\scriptsize}`.

A complete MWE and its output look like the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{atkinson}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\appto\TPTnoteSettings{\scriptsize}
\begin{document}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Test table}
\begin{tabular}{c c c}
Test & Test & Test\tnote{a}\\
Test & Test & Test\tnote{b}\\
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item [a] Note 1.
\item [b] Note 2.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. Your solution approach -- executing `\appto\TPTnoteSettings{\scriptsize}` -- doesn't seem to work if the `threeparttable` package is loaded with the option `flushleft`. Replacing `\appto\TPTnoteSettings{\scriptsize}` with `\AtBeginEnvironment{tablenotes}{\scriptsize}`, though, would appear to be robust to using the package's `flushleft` option.